# Reduce the size of a PDF file generated with PHPExcel

Tags: symfony-1.4, phpexcel

I am currently working on a project based on Symfony 1.4. To generate PDF files, I'm using the awesome PHPExcel library (through the sfPhpExcelPlugin). It works fine but I'm facing a problem : the generated PDF files, even empty, have a size bigger than 500kb.

Where does it come from ? Can I do something to reduce the filesize ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The switch to allow you to select from tcPDF, DomPDF or mPDF as a PDF rendering library will offer alternatives to the current tcPDF which does generate excessively large files. Both mPdf and DomPDF are faster and more memory efficient than tcPDF, and produce smaller output files, but each has its own inherent problems; and this work is not planned till the 1.7.8 release later this year.

Comment: Generating an HTML file from PHPExcel and then exporting it to PDF with domPDF or mPDF may be a good solution ?

Comment: At the moment, PHPExcel does generate an HTML, then uses tcPDF to convert that html to pdf. The change proposed for version 1.7.8 is to offer a choice of libraries that can perform that html->pdf conversion, but PHPExcel will still generate the HTML first and then call the appropriate library to handle the second step of the conversion

Comment: Ok so I am going to use PHPExcel for the first step only, then use the html-to-pdf converter I want without PHPExcel. Thanks a lot for your help.